# Asp.net URL rewriting (regular Expressions)

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I have the URLs like

http://somedomain.com/products.aspx?id=1

I want to rewrite this like

**somedomain.com/productname**

The rest of the URLs on the domain work as they are provided.
like

**somedomain.com/forums/categories.aspx**

I don't want to rewrite these other URLs.

Comment: What version of .NET? What URL rewriting library are you using?

Comment: I am using this sample,
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/urlrewriter.aspx

actually i am new to url rewriting, if anybody could suggest me any other easy way, i'll appreciate that.

thanks

Comment: Given the codeproject example, aren't you looking for "somedomain.com/product1.aspx" ?...i.e replace the "?id=1".

Comment: Actually i am looking for

somedomain.com/product1

just without  .aspx extension

so, it would be something like
somedomain.com/products.aspx?id=1       == somedomain.com/product1
somedomain.com/products.aspx?id=2       == somedomain.com/product2

Comment: and i need to call redirect action on specific kind of angular URLs, hardly can be achived without regex

Answer (score 0):

do like this in ur global.ascx file

from where u r redirecting on this, there page u can do like this there

response.redirect("somedomain.com/productname");

void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fullOrigionalpath = Request.Url.ToString();

```
    string[] words = fullOrigionalpath.Split('/');
    string d = words[words.Length-1].ToString();
    if (!d.EndsWith("aspx"))
    {
        Context.RewritePath("/products.aspx?id=1);
    }

}
```

Comment: its not just the products page,
as there are other pages too, that may be rewritten later.

So, thats why i want to handle this through the regular expressions.


<rule>
    <url>/URLRewriterM/s/h/o/w/(.*)\.html</url>
    <rewrite>/URLRewriterM/show.aspx?id=$1</rewrite>
   </rule>